# Java8 base image has java7 installed docker

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have attempted to create a custom docker image using a provided java8 base image as described [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/).

The following are the attempts I have made

- `FROM java`
- `FROM java:latest`
- `FROM java:8`
- `FROM java:8-jdk`

When the image was been created I checked the version of Java installed (`java -version`), all of which return

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

This is causing issues because my application is compiled to use Java 1.8. What java image should be used to actually get java8 on the container?

Answer (score 1):

Those should work, and do work for me. Are you sure you're building it and running the new image?

```
$ echo "FROM java:latest" > Dockerfile
$ docker build -t test .
...
$ docker run --rm test java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-1~bpo8+1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

You can view information about your local images using `docker inspect`. If you inspect one of the Java images you should the version of Java in the environment vars:

```
$ docker inspect java:latest
...
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
            "JAVA_VERSION=8u91",
            "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u91-b14-1~bpo8+1",
...
```

If you use `docker inspect` to view your image you should see these env vars as well, and can also compare the layers used to the Java image(s) to try and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

All the images you listed should be running java 8. Make sure you are building the image and running it in a new container after you update the Dockerfile.

```
echo "FROM java:8" > Dockerfile
docker build -t my-java:latest .
docker run --rm my-java:latest java -version
```